# Linking error when building OpenCV 3.0 with CMake and NMake

Tags: c++, opencv, build, cmake, nmake

Trying to build OpenCV 3.0 with CMake and NMake with commnads:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -G "NMake Makefiles" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DWITH_MSMF=OFF -DWITH_DSHOW=OFF -DWITH_VFW=OFF DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_CUDA=OFF ..`

and

`nmake`

I get

```
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: W:/VSONLINE/Passport-Photo/thirdparty/openc
v-3.0.0/build
nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Scanning dependencies of target zlib
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.obj
adler32.c
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.c.obj
compress.c
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.c.obj
crc32.c
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/deflate.c.obj
deflate.c
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.c.obj
gzclose.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.c.obj
gzlib.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.c.obj
gzread.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzwrite.c.obj
gzwrite.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inflate.c.obj
inflate.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/infback.c.obj
infback.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inftrees.c.obj
inftrees.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inffast.c.obj
inffast.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/trees.c.obj
trees.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/uncompr.c.obj
uncompr.c
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/zutil.c.obj
zutil.c
[  2%] Linking C static library ..\lib\zlib.lib
The system cannot find the path specified.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I have tried with Visual Studio 2010 and 2013 with exactly the same result.

**UPDATE**
If I change the generator to be "Visual Studio 10 2010" or any other version of Visual Studio and then build with `msbuild.exe OpenCV.sln` it all builds successfully. Is this a problem within `nmake` or `cmake`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known bug ([issue 5496](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5496)), which has been tagged as `wontfix`. 
In the comments the user *MarianMMX* suggested the following work-around:

> 1. Open CMakeLists.txt .
> 2. Go to line 70. (**Note:** it's line 90 in my case, so better do a text search)
> 3. Comment (or delete):
>
>    ```
>    #if(MSVC)
>    # set(CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS ON CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
>    #endif()
>    ```
> 4. Delete the generated files and rerun cmake.

I have successfully compiled [OpenCV 3.0.0](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.0.0.tar.gz) using `nmake` (VS2010 and VS2013) after
applying the above work-around:

```
> cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" <other options> <opencv src dir>
...
> nmake
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, just some debugging I've done.  The problem is not with linking.  The problem is with the cd commands that are piling up.  I haven't been able to find where these are in the CMake scripts, but somewhere, these are going wrong.  If you run the CMake configure step with:

```
 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=true
```

Then you'll see output like:

`[  2%] Linking C static library ..\lib\zlib.lib
        cd 3rdparty\zlib
        C:\Users\builder\Miniconda2\envs\_build\Library\bin\cmake.exe -P CMakeFiles\zlib.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
        cd ..\.. cd 3rdparty\zlib
The system cannot find the path specified.`

That latter cd line is very fishy - you can't chain two cd's together without some joining character there.  Something is going wrong with the NMake generator here - either due to the OpenCV source code, or due to CMake.

If you dig into the `build/3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/build.make` file, you'll see why this is happening: all of the `cd ..\..\` lines have that extra slash, which I think at the end of a line is line continuation, not the end of the path.